# Finding the 2 numbers closest to the number needed

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to take 2 of the closest numbers to average, in `avg_list`.

Also, is there any other way that I could re-write my code so that `x` contains 10 items instead of 6 items?

```python
    x1 = 461
    
    x2 = 336
    
    x3 = 267
    
    x4 = 262
    
    x5 = 212
    
    x6 = 318
    
    avg = (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6)/6
    
    
    avg1 = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3
    
    avg2 = (x1 + x2 + x4)/3
    
    avg3 = (x1 + x2 + x5)/3
    
    avg4 = (x1 + x2 + x6)/3
    
    avg5 = (x1 + x3 + x4)/3
    
    avg6 = (x1 + x5 + x5)/3
    
    avg7 = (x1 + x3 + x6)/3
    
    avg8 = (x1 + x4 + x5)/3
    
    avg9 = (x1 + x4 + x6)/3
    
    avg10 = (x1 + x5 + x6)/3
    
    avg11 = (x2 + x3 + x4)/3
    
    avg12 = (x2 + x3 + x5)/3
    
    avg13 = (x2 + x3 + x6)/3
    
    avg14 = (x2 + x4 + x5)/3
    
    avg15 = (x2 + x4 + x6)/3
    
    avg16 = (x2 + x5 + x6)/3
    
    avg17 = (x3 + x4 + x5)/3
    
    avg18 = (x3 + x4 + x6)/3
    
    avg19 = (x3 + x5 + x6)/3
    
    avg20 = (x4 + x5 + x6)/3
    
    avg_list = [avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5, avg6, avg7, avg8, avg9, avg10, avg11, avg12, avg13, avg14, avg15, 
    avg16, avg17, avg18, avg19, avg20]
```

Comment: this looks like a work-intensive way to do things.  What exactly do avgs 1-20 represent?

Comment: Minh, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to code this? If so, can you share your code.

Comment: Are you looking for two closest or two smallest? If it is two smallest, then you sort the numbers in ascending order. Then take the first 3 to be the lowest average, then the first two + 4th one. That will be the lowest averages of the list of numbers.   If you are looking for two averages close to each other, then find the sum of 3 numbers that are close to each other. The averages of both will be close to each other.

Comment: For the above question, is your answer  [212, 262, 267]=247.0 and [262,267,318]=282.34

Comment: After doing all the math, it looks like `(212+267+318)/3 = 265.67` and `(212+262+318)/3 = 264.0.` with a difference between these two of 1.67 is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

Getting combinations with `itertools.combinations` will help.  I've additionally done some stuff with numpy (fast arrays) instead of lists where convenient.  A note that if your combinations list becomes very large, there are further efficiencies possible (don't sort the full output, numpy probably has a combinations function).

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np


def get_closest_partial_avgs(x, n=3):
    # returns array of partial averages for n elements    
    ave = np.mean(x)
    partial_aves = []
    for vals in combinations(x, n):
        partial_avg = sum(vals)/n            
        partial_aves.append(partial_avg)
        partial_aves = sorted(partial_aves, key=lambda x: np.abs(x -ave))[0:2]
    return partial_aves    


# example

x = [461, 336, 267, 262, 212, 318]

best_aves = get_closest_partial_avgs(x, n=3)
# best_aves = [307.0, 311.6666666666667]
```

Comment: I dont think you need to get the combinations. There may be an alternate way to solve for this. Going through all the combinations will be time consuming

Comment: its not the most efficient but maybe the clearest

Comment: I guess it would be better to put the comparison in the function and only retain the closest two averages.  I'll update

Comment: Your code gives the answers [307. , 311.66666667]. I dont think these are the two closest values

Comment: still results in 307 and 311. The answers should be [212, 262, 267]=247.0 and [262,267,318]=282.34

Comment: I don't know where you get those numbers but they're wrong @JoeFerndz

Comment: Got it. Sorry about the math. I see the delta of the two to be the smallest

Comment: Sorry, going back to this. `(212+267+318)/3 = 265.67` and `(212+262+318)/3 = 264.0`. The difference between these two is 1.67 and is the closest. I think these should have been the answer

Comment: @JoeFerndz I think they're looking for the two values closest to the full `average`, not to themselves

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import statistics as sc
import numpy as np
def nearest_numbers_avg(x_list,n):
    avg_list = []
    diff = []
    tot_avg = sc.mean(x_list)
    x_sublist = list(itertools.permutations(x_list,int(len(x_list)/2)))
    for i in x_sublist:
        avg = sc.mean(i)
        avg_list.append(avg)
    diff = abs(np.asarray(avg_list)-tot_avg)
    diff = diff.tolist()
    for i in range(n):
        lst.append(avg_list[diff.index(sorted(diff)[i])])
    return(x_sublist)
```

Comment: it would be cool, if you add comments to explain what happens in your piece of code

Answer (score -1):

There are things in computer programming named "***arrays***".

An "***array***" is like a row of squares on a sheet of graph paper.

[image: PICTURE_OF_AN_ARRAY]

There are many ways to create an array.

One of which is shown below:

```python
x = [None]*6
print(x)
```

The console output is as follows:

```python
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

If you write `x = [None]*6` then `x` will contain 6 things.

If you write `x = [None]*10` then `x` will contain 10 things.

You should ***not*** write variable names like `x1`, `x2`, `x3`

Instead, use square brackets `[]` like this:

```python
x = [None]*7
x[1] = 461
x[2] = 336
x[3] = 267
x[4] = 262
x[5] = 212
x[6] = 318

print(x)
```

If you print `x`, you will notice that `x` is `[None, 461, 336, 267, 262, 212, 318]`

The left-most square in the row of squares of graph paper is `x[0]`

The first thing in the row of graph paper is named `x[0]`, not `x[1]`

[image: array with indexing shown]

If you want to compute an average, there are different ways to do it:

```python
average_of_x = sum(x)/len(x)
```

Sometimes you will get the following error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python_sandbox/fgfnxxfgh.py", line 12, in <module>
    average_of_x = sum(x)/len(x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

That error means that some of the things in your row of squares are not numbers.

The computer does ***not*** understand `4 + "egg"` or `98 + a house`

The computer usually adds numbers to other numbers.  `1 + 92 + 81 + 1 + 5`

The following makes an error:

```python
data = [None, 443, None, 27, 19, 19 , 8, 19]

total = sum(data)
```

The following are almost the same:

```python
avg = (x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6])/6
avg = sum(x)/len(x)
```

You should never write `avg1`, `avg2`, `avg3`, etc...

Instead, write, `avg[1]`, `avg[2]`, `avg[3]`.

The following is not very good code, but it is better than what you wrote originally (relatively speaking):

```python
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def n_choose_r(n, r):
    """
    If n == 6, and r == 3, then this function computes
    the number of ways to draw three numbers from the set
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    
    examples of sets of size 3 drawn from {1...6} are shown below:
    {1, 2, 3}
    {1, 2, 4}
    {1, 2, 5}
    {1, 2, 6}
    {1, 3, 4}
    """
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom  


avg = [None]*n_choose_r(len(x), 3)
max_ = len(x)
i = 0
for k1 in range(1, 1+ max_):
    for k2 in range(k1 + 1, 1 + max_):
        for k3 in range(k2 + 1, 1 + max_):
             avg[i] = (x[k1] + x[k2] + x[k3])/3
             i = i + 1
```